# can you please look out for that schenario

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

i have  two role for my project from thought of trying something new. so i  created one table " clinicid"  in my database with staffid and doctorid attribute in it. and while someonoe does registration. that person need to enter a code that is either equall to staffid or doctorid in  clinicid collection. and if that code matches with doctor id it should open doct dashboard and staff then staff dashboard.
i am doing in node js with mongodb and frontend as a recat.i just need a code that would help me out for this scenario.please bro it would be very graceful. Thank you.
here is a code of my registration  and login in node js.
in short when person tries to register with username, password and code. that code should match with database collection of clinic id with either staffid or docid. and if i am doing it wrong can you suggest me something different.

```
router.post('/register' ,( req,res,next)=>{
let {username,password,code}= req.body;





User.find({ username})
.then(user =>{
    if(!user){
        throw new Error('User already exist');
    }

bcrypt.hash(password,10, (err,hash)=>{
    if (err)  return next(err);
    User.create({username, password: hash,code})
    .then(user =>{
        res.json({status:"Signup success"});
    }).catch(next);
})


   
}).catch(function(err){
    next(err)
}
);
});
router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=>{
    const  {username, password,} = req.body;
User.findOne({username})
.then((user)=>{
    if(!user){
        let err = new Error('User  does not exist');
        err.status=400;
        return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    .then((isMatched)=>{
        if (!isMatched){
            let err = Error('Password doesnot match');
            err.status=400;
            return next(err);
        }
        const payload ={
            id:user.id,
            username:user.username,
            role:user.role
        }
        jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET,{expiresIn: '3hr'},(err, token)=>{
            if (err) return  next(err);
                        res.json({message:'Login successfull', token});
        })
    })
}).catch(next);
})
```